Invalid hook call in react native
im tring to call this hook but im receiving this error
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 6):
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

this is my code:
const handleEvento = async (dayy) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://192.168.15.11:8085/api/readEventsByDate/${dayy}`)
         .then(response => {
           // Ordenar os dados pelo id em ordem crescente
           const sortData = response.data.sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id);
    
           setData2(sortData);

           console.log(data2)
         })
       .catch(error => {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
  },[]);
}

onDayPress={day => {
    handleEvento(day.dateString)        
}}

i really dont know what im missing here if soomeone can helps i would be really glad

Can you post the entire contents of that file? It looks like the file isnt being recognized as React Component, or a React Hook

see https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning#breaking-rules-of-hooks, particularly the bullet point "Do not call Hooks in event handlers", which is exactly what you're doing here. It's likely the appropriate fix is just to remove the useEffect (I can't guess what its purpose is) and just to call fetch directly inside the handler - but without knowing 100% what your requirements are it's possible that something else may be needed.

React hooks rely on the order of calling, so there are some rules how to use them. It's described in the Using Hooks part of the documentation. In short: you can't use hooks like you did, because it makes the call order unpredictable.
In your case, it looks like useEffect() is used incorrectly also from the logical perspective. You can just skip it entirely:
const handleEvento = async (dayy) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://192.168.15.11:8085/api/readEventsByDate/${dayy}`);

    //Ordenar os dados pelo id em ordem crescente
    const sortData = response.data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

    setData2(sortData);

    console.log(data2);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
};

Notice how I also simplified your code by using await.
One more note - your console.log(data2) will not log the latest value, because setData2() only queues state for updating. It's going to be effectively changed at the end of the current cycle.

You have used async without an await functionality. Please check and make changes accordingly. Since the useEffect hook cannot be used inside another function, use the function inside useEffect as below.
Note: Hooks cannot be used as callbacks directly inside any other function.
useEffect(() => {
  handleEvento();
}, []);

const handleEvento = async (dayy) => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.get(
      `http://192.168.15.11:8085/api/readEventsByDate/${dayy}`,
    );
    result.then((response) => {
      //Ordenar os dados pelo id em ordem crescente
      const sortData = response.data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

      setData2(sortData);

      console.log(data2);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
};

